# Special Chars � are coming in data which were sent from wysiwyg editor

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I have a WYSIWYG editor in one of my forms. But even on simple content (without any html tags) which is submitted from that editor, the blank space gets converted into `&nbsp;`.

I use `html_entity_decode()` function to show the content on webpage again, but those `&nbsp;` are shown as special � characters.

I dont know where I am going wrong. I have mentioned `accept-charset="utf-8"` in form too.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Have a look at the [manual page of `html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode), especially at its optional parameters.